# Alexa for Business - Using Alexa for conference room

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I am trying to configure the newly released Alexa for Business module for my Echo Device.

I followed all the steps suggested in the videos released by Alexa. However I keep running into the problem "Sync in progress" for the Echo device settings and end up not getting any kind of sync done.
The Echo Dot has latest version updated. 
Nothing is clearly mentioned in the forums of Amazon for Business to trouble shoot.

Anyone has run into this issue? Any suggestions regarding what to do?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. Have you managed to fix?

Comment: Did either of you ask Amazon? "Business module" sounds pricey, which would seem to expect good support from them. Also, if it is fairly new, they don't want it getting bad feedback before it can gain market traction, so *ought* to be inclined to help.

Comment: Could you specify your location, @praveen? [This forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270482&tstart=0) suggests that [Alexa for Business isn't supported outside the US](https://aws.amazon.com/alexaforbusiness/faqs/), and if so, that might be the problem.

Comment: Hi , I am in NL but I use a US address.

Comment: I am in NL but I am using a US server and our US address.
Alexa for home had the same challenges. But with US address it works

Comment: did you manage to get your Echo device setup ? I'm having the same problem with adding a Device.